# How to open AOSP default launcher app Launcher3 in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-source

I cloned Launcher3, which is the default launcher for AOSP: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher3/+/refs/tags/android-11.0.0_r28

I opened it on Android Studio and got

```
01:04   Gradle sync failed: com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.issues.SdkPlatformNotFoundException: Module: 'Launcher3' platform 'android-R' not found. (1 m 34 s 191 ms)
```

What is wrong? I made sure Android 11 SDK is downloaded

Comment: `R` class isn't available in that ~ I guess.

Answer (score 2):

You can not directly compile / add AOSP projects in Android Studio since they follow the AOSP build system. That said, you should try importing the sources using
"idegen" tool at first.

Follow these for reference:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/refs/heads/master/tools/idegen/README

https://wiki.lineageos.org/how-to/import-to-android-studio

Answer (score 0):

While building using Android.mk / .bp is indeed better supported for AOSP projects, I believe you can fix the `android-R` problem by setting `COMPILE_SDK=30` in [gradle.properties](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher3/+/refs/heads/master/gradle.properties#13)